# how to get Region using Specified string in GoogleMaps in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, string, search, mkmapview

In my iphone application i am using MKMapView to display any region(i.e Australia) and it is working fine using coordinates(latitude and longitude).But i want to display the region based on the string (i.e Australia) instead of the coordinates.
Lets say i click on the TableView with named string as "Australia" and in the next view it should display Australia with some pinpoints on that.

how to display any region based on the String instead of the given coordinates?

provide any solution with any code snippet or any useful link or any other ,which would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Geocoding](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Querying the server for "Australia" should return the coordinates you need.